# How to create a stored procedure with a combination of 3 columns as the parameter?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, combinations

I need to create a report based on 3 columns- the parameters from the report to the stored procedure will be a combination of the 3 columns.

For example there is a table with columns:

```
patientname, patient_no, hospital_no, doctor_code, service_used
```

The report will have 1 parameter as the input, like `hospital_nodoctor_codeservice_used`.

(combination of 3 columns in the table) and all the patients with that combinations has to be returned? how can this be done?

I have not created the report too, so if I have to make the default value in the parameter like

```
hospital_no|doctor_code|service_used
```

anything is possible. But I don't know how to do it. Help please!!!

Table is like

```
patientname    patient_no    hospital_no   doctor_code    service_used
----------------------------------------------------------------------    
name1            1252           hosp1          doc12            OT_1
name2            2533           hosp2          doc12            IP_1
NAME3             1212          HOSP6          doc2             OP_1
name4             1111          HOSP6          doc2             OP_1
name5             2222          HOSP6          doc2             OP_1
```

the report will have a parameter like `HOSP6doc2OP_1` and it has to be passed to the stored procedure (combination of the 3 columns-hospital_no doctor_code  service_used)
and the output should be like , (it should pull the values based on the 3 columns)

```
name4             1111             HOSP6          doc2             OP_1
name5             2222             HOSP6          doc2             OP_1
NAME3             1212             HOSP6          doc2             OP_1
```

The 3 parameters will be like a drop down menu with the combination of these parameters hardcoded in the crystal report. for this report, 4 combinations are actually needed. so those will be as 4 parameters for the report(different combinations).Also, yes i know i can just use 3 separate parameters in the report, but...the business owner wants the report this way, so i am helpless about it.

Comment: Please provide some sample input and what you want done with it.  Your run-on paragraph doesn't do your problem justice.

Comment: This is a **horribly bad design** - if you have **three parameters** - why aren't you just passing **three parameters**?!?!? This would make **your life** a whole lot easier! Stop fiddling around with combining and then parsing multiple parameters - if you need three parameters, use three separate parameters!

Comment: Well, the requirement is that way, i am just the programmer. I asked, But the Business owner wants it this way. I cant do anything about it.The 3 parameters will be like a drop down menu with the combination of the parameters hardcoded in the crystal report. for this report, 4 combinations are actually needed. so those will be as 4 parameters for the report(different combinations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the order that the ***4 parameters*** will be hardcoded in then you can use the concatenated version in your where ie:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name+Surname+Number+Age = @ReportParam
```

Comment: Thankyou.. ah.. why didnt i think of this.. lol.. i was thinking about some function to parse the parameter.. lol. thankyou so much man!

Comment: No worries. . .nothing solves a problem like a fresh pair of eyes